# Linear transformation followed by change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have this problem:

[image]

I've attempted calculating: $[L(v_1)]_T$ but cannot understand where I'm going wrong. Apparently the answer is (1, -1).  Here is my attempt:

[image]

Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong? I think I did something wrong in the transformation  but I'm not sure why.

Comment: You can typeset mathematics with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\;Lv_i\;$ is simply the $\;i\,-$ th **column** in the matrix representing $\;L\;$ wrt those basis: this is *precisely* the definition of matrix wrt basis!

Comment: @DonAntonio, true. But I'd say this is a clever exercise since knowing definition and understanding it are different things. Even more so if you don't really know definition precisely.

Comment: @Ennar And that is why I remarked that that is precisely how we define this thing. A careful student will go and read his notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A$ is matrix of $L$ in pair of bases $S$ and $T$, to calculate $Lv_1$ using $A$ you first need to write $v_1$ in basis $S$.

Comment: That's the thing that confuses me. Isn't $v_1$ a vector that is part of the basis S? Is it somehow saying to write the vector in terms of the basis it makes up?

Comment: @dj1121, let me ask you, what do you think $[-1, 1, 0]$ stands for?

Comment: Ahh wait a minute. Ok so I know that the columns of the matrix representing the transformation are just the transformation applied to the column vectors in the basis. In this case they're coming from S but how should I know that they come from S? Why not from T? Is that because the basis S is a basis for R3 and the transformation goes from R3 -> R2? So that means [-1,1,0] is $v_1$ before you apply the transformation so it's $[v_1]_s$ right?

Comment: @dj1121, let's step back a bit. $[-1,1,0]$ is just a convenient way to express a vector in a basis. Since it doesn't say otherwise, you should assume it's canonical basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$. Thus, $[-1,1,0]$ represents $-e_1 + e_2.$ But, your matrix accepts vector columns in basis $S$, not in canonical basis, so you multiplying $A\, [-1,1,0]$ calculates $L(-v_1+v_2)$, not $Lv_1$. What you need to do is find a column vector $[a,b,c]$ such that $av_1+bv_2+cv_3 = v_1$ and then calculate $A\, [a,b,c]$ to get $Lv_1$.

Comment: What I want to say is that you know that $v_1$ is represented by $[-1,1,0]$ in canonical basis. But when you give that column vector to matrix $A$, it doesn't know that you mean vector $v_1$, it thinks that $[-1,1,0]$ is in basis $S$, so for $A$ column $[-1,1,0]$ means $-v_1+v_2$. You have to write $v_1$ in a way that $A$ understands.

Comment: I think I get it. So when we wrote $v_1$ it's in canonical basis of R3 but since A represents a transformation in terms of basis S and T, we need to first convert it to S? Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to use it in the matrix since we're not talking about a transformation using canonical basis. So it seems I've learned that the vectors that make up bases are (unless otherwise told) canonical.

Comment: Yes, you need to write $v_1$ in $S$, as I wrote in my answer :) It might be confusing that it's very easy to write $v_1$ in basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. But then again, $e_1$ is also very easy to write in canonical basis.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for sticking with me.Is there any difference between this method here and what is shown in this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trqq8Ot6vkc

I'm trying to tie it all together. I think he is saying the same thing as we talked about.

Comment: @dj1121, I have no idea, don't know the video. If you have more questions, you should ask a new question here on math.SE.

Comment: No worries, you're not obligated to watch. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

In the given basis

$$L(v_1)=A\cdot v_1=[1,-1]=1\cdot w_1-1\cdot w_2$$

and so on.